# Какие инструменты нужны, чтобы начать писать на Objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

По работе появилась нужда понять в общих чертах как ведется разработка под IOS. Как показал Гугл, нам потребуется язык Objective-c. Но я честно говоря не могу понять, где собственно можно написать свой первый "Hello world" на этом языке? 
К примеру с той же джавой/скалой/js я использую intelijIDEA. Но вот тут я что-то не пойму какой софт использовать. Собственно у меня есть Макбук, есть ли там какая-то встроенная среда программирования на Objective-c? Если нет, то что поставить/скачать/купить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам достаточно сделать следующее:

1. Зарегистрировать учетную запись разработчика apple https://developer.apple.com Абсолютно бесплатно.
2. Достать компьютер работающий под управлением MAC OSX
3. Установить программный пакет разработчика apple: Xcode зайдя на https://developer.apple.com под своей учетной записью, абсолютно
   бесплатно.
4. Начать программировать!
5. Запускать программный код из среды xCode можно как на своих устройствах с iOS, так и на эмуляторах этих устройств, которые идут в комплекте с xCode.

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле Вам и учетную запись разработчика не обязательно иметь. Для того чтоб пробовать писать на ObjC, Swift, достаточно AppleID, и через AppStore на macOS скачать полностью бесплатный Xcode.

Comment: вообще я так и сделал, но думал, что при этом выполнил алгоритм первого комментатора)